# Marking chunks of data in a binary file

Tags: java, c#, binaryfiles

I'm writing save logic for an application and part of it will save a dynamic list of "chunks" of data to a single file. Some of those chunks might have been provided by a plugin though (which would have included logic to read it back), so I need to find a way to properly skip unrecognized chunks of data if the plugin which created it has been removed.

My current solution is to write a length (int32) before each "chunk" so if there's an error the reader can skip past it and continue reading the next chunk.

However, this requires calculating the length of the data *before* writing any of it, and since our system is somewhat dynamic and allows nested data types, I'd rather avoid the overhead of caching everything just to measure it.

I'm considering using file markers somehow - I could scan the file for a very specific byte sequence that separates chunks. That could be written after each chunk rather than before.

Are other options I'm not thinking of? My goal is to find a way to write the data as immediately, without the need for caching and measuring it.

Comment: How about having an emum of supported handlers of chunks. And simply write the enum id before the chunk. That way, if you remove a plugin, then that plugin's id can be ignored for that chunk. And roll on to the next. As there's no code, it's a little difficult to tell if I've picked you up correctly from your description, but it doesn't sound too difficult. You will need to know which plugins are loaded though to be able to check against the chunk's handler id, if that makes sense? Also, do your chunks have a sensible maximum limit to their size? You could simply divide up by the max size.

Comment: There is no guarantee that with TCP that your chunks will be i the same size as you sent them.  tCP datagrams have max size of ~1500 bytes.but routers and servers can split and recombine data.  So a 1450 datagram and 1475 datagram sent can be received as 1460 and 1465.  This sin't going to make a real difference in the middle of a long message, but you still have a method to determine when you get the the last byte.

Comment: @ManoDestra Yes you've got a handle on it. We do have a registry and can match up chunks with an owner, and that's all working currently. I'm likely going to switch to a marker, I just need to choose something unique so I can scan through unrecognized chunks to find the next one.

Comment: @jdweng This is all done with a file on disk, there's no networking involved.

Comment: @helion3 Yes, that sounds like a reasonable solution to me.